# How to fetch json response instead of html response from a get request?

Tags: json, get, httpresponse, postman

Opening https://www.coinome.com/exchange/data.json in browser shows a json,but while trying to fetch response by making a GET request,the returned response is in html format.

How to get JSON response instead of html response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because the first time you perform the request to that url, the server returns an html form to check whether youare human or not.

Then after you compile and submit the form a cookie is returned.

You have to save that cookie and redo the request to the same url while putting the cookie in the request header in order to get the response in json format.